# Using Flask-OIDC with local OpenID Connect Server

Tags: python, flask, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have created a Flask app and I want to protect it with authorization against an existing local OpenID Connect server implemented in IdentityServer4.

On the official documentation for Flask-OIDC, i have found this part:

```
@app.route('/api')
@oidc.accept_token()
def my_api():
    return json.dumps('Welcome %s' % g.oidc_token_info['sub'])
```

"if you are only using this part of flask-oidc, it is suggested to set the configuration option OIDC_RESOURCE_SERVER_ONLY (new in 1.0.5)."

It makes sense that i need to decorate the endpoint to protect it. However, i can't seem to find docs for how to reference an exisiting OpenID Connect endpoint and use that to verify the token.

How do I accomplish this?